# Rails: Can you have render html: in a controller populate a div in the current view?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am building a form for a Model called `SchoolApplication`. If someone unsuccessfully  fills out the form, I would like to render a bit of HTML above the form saying `<strong> you messed up</strong>`. Currently I have 
some logic in the controller corresponding to my form that says:

```
if @school_application.save
  redirect_to relevant_path
else
  render html: '<strong>you messed up </strong>'
end
```

However instead of rendering this in the new page it just displays the text (including the HTML tags)
 **you messed up** .

Is there a way I can have this message rendered on the page displayed before render redirected me? Specifically in a `<div>` created for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the rails `flash` variable to do this, from the documentation, you can do something like this:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      # ...
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not save client"
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash for more details

also a common 'gotcha', don't forget to put a variation of this in your `application.html.erb`

```
<html>
  <!-- <head/> -->
  <body>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
    <% end -%>

    <!-- more content -->
  </body>
</html>
```